# Javascript object not recognizing function

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript class defined as below:

```
function Node(init, parent) {
  this.value = init;
  this.children = [];
  this.updateChildren(this.value);
}

Node.prototype.updateChildren = function(value) {
  this.children.push(value);
 };
```

When I run it.. i receive the error,

```
this.updateChildren() is not defined.
```

Any clue what I am missing here ?

Full code here :

```js
'use strict';

var millionNumbers = [];

for (var i = 2; i< 1000000; i++) {
  if (!millionNumbers[i]) {
    millionNumbers[i] = new Node(i, null);
  }
}

function Node(init, parent) {
  this.value = init;
  this.children = [];
  if (parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  var newValue;
  
  if (isEven(this.value)) {
    newValue = this.value/2;
  } else {
    newValue = (this.value * 3) + 1;
  }

  //whether newValue is 1 or something else, we still have add it to the children list
  this.updateChildren(newValue);

  if (millionNumbers[newValue]) {
    var chainedNode = millionNumbers[newValue];
    this.children.concat(chainedNode.children);
  }

  if (newValue === 1) {
    this.endChain();
  } else {
    new Node(newValue, this);
  }

}

Node.prototype.updateChildren = function(value) {
  this.children.push(value);
  if(this.parent) {
    this.parent.updateChildren(value);
  }
};

Node.prototype.endChain = function() {
    if (!millionNumbers[this.value]) {
      millionNumbers[this.value] = this;
      this.parent = null;
    }
  };
  
function isEven(value) {

  if (value % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: The only issue I can see is that you're calling `this.updateChildren(value)` instead of `this.updateChildren(init)` or `this.updateChildren(this.value)`.

Comment: @zzzzBov.. I am calling it that way

Comment: @SMV Then it should work... https://jsfiddle.net/b5094wt5/

Comment: @SMV, you are now after you updated the question, but you're not calling `new Node()` anywhere in  your example code, so I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: Did you possibly forget to use the `new` keyword when calling the function?

Comment: @zzzzBov see the plnkr link

Comment: @Oka do you have a solution to offer or just useless comments ?

Comment: @Oka don't bother.. you need a refresher course on politeness and social interaction

Comment: @SMV Alright, suit yourself. Try reading [_How do I ask a good question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop instantiates Node objects before `Node.prototype.updateChildren` is set, so within the Node constructor, `this.updateChildren` is still undefined.

To fix the problem, just move the `for` loop to the end of the file.

<sub>Also: Best of luck with the Collatz conjecture!</sub>

Answer (score -1):

think you are calling these classes without defining them first. 
You can try this way:

```
 function updateChildren(value) {
  this.children.push(value);
 };

function Node(init, parent) {
  this.value = init;
  this.children = [];
  this.updateChildren(value);
}

Node.prototype.updateChildren(value);
```